# Maatwebsite Excel can't import chinese character

Tags: excel, laravel, import

I use this laravel package, but It can't not work when I write chinese document,
and import that to my database which only showed '0' on my column.
How should I fix this problem?

I must input my name column to be chinese, but my databse showed '0' in that column.

This is my excel.php import part:

````
        'read_only' => true,

        'heading_row' => [

            /*
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Heading Row Formatter
            |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |
            | Configure the heading row formatter.
            | Available options: none|slug|custom
            |
            */
            'formatter' => 'slug',
        ],

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | CSV Settings
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | Configure e.g. delimiter, enclosure and line ending for CSV imports.
        |
        */
        'csv'         => [
            'delimiter'              => ',',
            'enclosure'              => '"',
            'escape_character'       => '\\',
            'contiguous'             => false,
            'input_encoding'         => 'UTF-8',
        ],

```    ],

  and my excel model code is:

```<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;

class ExcelImport3 implements ToModel
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    use Importable;
    public function model(array $row)
    {

        return new BalAddress([
             'name' => $row[0], 
             'addr' => $row[1],
             'certificate' => $row[2],
             'establish_date' => $row[3],
             'establish_id' => $row[4],
             'certificate_number' => $row[5],
        ]);
    }

```}
````

Comment: Please, instead of the image paste the code in your question

Comment: Hi, Cesar. I put my code on the post. And I still not fix this.

Comment: Hi, Ceasar. I have fixed this issue!